# Reduce clickable area for an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a left navigation bar using buttons. I'm trying to reduce the hyperlink area to just the background image. Also, another issue I'm having is the elements overlaying the background image are taking precedence over the hyperlink, so the button is not actually clickable. Page for reference
http://www.auburn.edu/administration/facilities/home-page/index.html

Hyperlink area

[image]

Here's the background image area

[image]

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.background:hover .head {
    color: #d76e08;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
}
.icon {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.head {
    margin-top: -75px;
    padding-left: 120px;
}
.content {
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 35px;
}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="background">
            <a href="../Collin/misc/issues/index.html">
                <img alt="background" class="img-responsive" src="buttons/images/button.png" />
            </a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img alt="test" class="img-responsive" src="buttons/images/info-icon.png" />
                </div>
                <p class="head">Ask Facilities</p>
                <p class="content">Here will be text about the button. .</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would never post the original site details for which I am working for. You should have created a dummy page to show the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to reduce the hyperlink area to just the background image.

Your markup is incredibly complex for what you are displaying.

You could have something like:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and add the image and the gradient using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single link tag for your button and leverage CSS gradients for the background:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3D85C6, #07355F 50%, #07355F);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  background-position: 0 50%;
}

.button-icon {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.button-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button-description {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="../Collin/misc/issues/index.html">
  <div class="button-icon">
    <img src="http://satyr.io/72/white?brand=github" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="button-content">
    <p class="button-title">Ask Facilities</p>
    <p class="button-description">Here will be text about the button…</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Also here http://jsbin.com/rikisemawe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: You may need to apply browser vendor prefixes depending on what level of support you need. Also, I intentionally left the `alt` text blank since it is decorative and should not be read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in OP were stacked in the markup, there were no nested components of the button. That would explain the unusual position coords and large padding.
Instead of `<img>`, `background-image` is used. Changed some of the tags to a real `<button>`, `<h4>` instead of `<p>`, etc.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 95px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: url(http://www.auburn.edu/administration/facilities/home-page/buttons/images/button.png)no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.background:hover .head {
  color: #d76e08;
}
.text {
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 85px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #def;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover,
.text:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #def;
}
.button:hover .head {
  color: gold;
}
.icon {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 37.5px);
  background: url(http://www.auburn.edu/administration/facilities/home-page/buttons/images/service-icon.png)no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">


    <button class="button">

      <div class="icon"></div>
      <a class='text'>
        <h4 class="head">Ask Facilities</h4>
        <p class="content">Here will be text about the button.</p>
      </a>

    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```